# Published app not available on BR Apple Store

Tags: ios, iphone

Apple approved my application and it is "Ready For Sale" (5 hours ago apple approved it).
I can't find my app and when I try to open it with Itunes Connect I get the message saying that my app it's not available on Brazilian App Store.

On Itunes Connect >> My App >> Pricing I "have" the message: Unless you select specific territories, your app will be for sale in all App Store territories worldwide.

If I click on "specific territories" all the countries are "checked".

What is the problem? There is anyway to solve it without uploading a new version?

Comment: Just wait some time...

Comment: @sha this is normal? How much time? Because I never get an error like this.

Comment: It's unpredictable. Sometime can go up to 24 hours. They have a lot of servers to propagate the changes.

Comment: Hi @sha it couldn't be a problem with my upload or app configuration? Still out of apple store with same message error. :(

Comment: What's the link to the app? I can check it in US store

Comment: Hi @sha https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/festuris/id934516850?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Nope. Not available in the US AppStore either

Comment: @sha do you think that in 24h it's available? Every app that I uploaded instantly (or almost) was on app store :(